# convert iphone xib into ipad in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My project is completed for iPhone but now I have to convert it in universal. So I want to know What is the best and quick way to convert iPhone xib to iPad xib in Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your app into a universal app follow these steps:

1. Create new xib files specific to iPad
2. Load specific xib file in your code i.e apply a check to see if the device is iPad or iPhone and then load the specific xib file. Check simply looks like this:

   ```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // load iPhone xib and write code
    }
   else
   {
    // load iPad xib and write code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use Auto Layout for using only 1 xib
2. You could make multiple xibs and load iPhone or iPad depending on which device is in currently in use

The easiest way is probably number 2. Just make the same connections as there are for iPhone on an another xib with the same interface.

[Here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/07/converting-to-a-universal-app-part-i.html) is an example of how to go about making your app universal.